# An error occurred when switching from UIWebView to WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wkwebview

I am developing an iOS application with `Objective-C`,
I wanted to move from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`.

However, an error occurred in the part which I wrote in this way before.

```
    WKWebView * webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    ...
    if (! webview.request) {
        ...
    }
```

The errors are as follows.

> Property 'request' not found on object of type 'WKWebView *'

If you can understand, please tell me how to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: error message is clear `WKWebView` don't have `request` property you should use `load(_ request: URLRequest) -> WKNavigation?` method

Comment: Hello.
I have been using Objective-C for a week now.
Please tell me more details such as URL.

Comment: what you exactly want? open url or any thing else?

Comment: If you're new to `objective-c` (or any language), the most important thing is to learn where to find the documentation. So in this case here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview?language=objc

Comment: any feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Error message is clear `WKWebView` don't have `request` property you should use `load(_ request: URLRequest) -> WKNavigation?` method and check for url property instead

as is defined in `WKWebView` class

```
/*! @abstract The active URL.
 @discussion This is the URL that should be reflected in the user
 interface.
 @link WKWebView @/link is key-value observing (KVO) compliant for this
 property.
 */
open var url: URL? { get }
```

your code should be

```
WKWebView * webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
...
if (!webview.url) {
    ...
}
```